# Kinect to PC connection through controller USB3.0

Tags: usb, kinect

I used Kinect 2.0 connected to motherboard Gigabyte through ST-Lab U710 USB3.0 PCI-E-1 controller (claim SuperSpeed) inserted in PCI-E-16 of course. All SDK samples works fine but there are no Super Speed in driver hub usb3.0 so I get only 7 fps not 30.

I bought Foxconn H67S/H61SP motherboard, because it's claim Super Speed in PCI-E-16. I use ST-Lab U710 USB3.0 PCI-E-1 controller in PCI-E-16 again. But speed is 7 fps only and no SuperSpeed words in driver hub. Also I need make Disable\Enable HD Video Graphics for start Kinect demo now. (Disable\Enable KInect or controller USB not help.)

When I connect Kinect to more expensive MBs with USB3.0 integrated all works fine and speed is 30 fps.

My question: How to get words "Super Speed" in driver of ST-Lab U710 controller (chip Renesas\NEC mPD720202 - claim SuperSpeed)?

Also Why Host Controller Utility say: "There is not any controller USB3.0" though it works? May be controller don't turn on Super Speed?

I use Win8.1 64 bit and drivers from 2015 Drivers Pack Solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the Kinect v2 works (even if only at low FPS), it is most likely not an USB problem. If the Kinect v2 can't connect as a superspeed device, it won't work at all.

It's more likely that your CPU and/or graphics card is too slow. The [System Requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn782036.aspx) claim you need the following:

- 4 GB Memory (or more)
- I7 3.1 GHz (or higher)
- DX11 capable graphics adapter

But that's pretty vague and the resulting FPS can vary widely, depending on your specific setup.

Comment: Ok. Simple question: I have 3 motherboards: (Gigabyte,Foxconn, MSI). I install USB3.0 controller (ST-Lab U710)  in  PCI-E-16. How to get string "Hub is operating at super-speed" in driver of USB Root Hub of  controller (chip Renesas\NEC mPD720202 - claim SuperSpeed)? (I see "Hub is operating at high-speed")

Comment: I insert flash-stick USB3.0 and copy 10 GByte file to HDD. At first few sec I see speed is 600 MByte\sec i.e. near standart USB3.0 5 GBit\sec. Then it low to 66 MByte\sec. I see that  at begin it show the speed of transfer to cash and then speed of HDD. So flash+controller+driver really work at 5 GBit\sec?